# How to handle subsequent SSO logins with OAuth 2.0 / OpenID Connect?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am trying to figure out how my server can check if a user has previously logged in via SSO authentication with some 3rd-party identity provider (ex: Facebook).

Looking at the [JWT documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), there are two claims that stick out to me:

- `iss` - The "iss" (issuer) claim identifies the principal that issued the
  JWT
- `sub` - The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the
  subject of the JWT.

Can I guarantee these two claims will be the same if an existing user subsequently logs in via Facebook again? In other words, can I store these two values in a database, and when the user logs in again via Facebook I can query these values and confirm s/he already exists?

For comparison, I know SAML uses a federation ID that is always consistent for each user. Is there something similar for OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the OAuth user ID in a database is a pretty standard technique, though not all providers are standards based:

- How the sub claim is set varies between vendors, but usually there is always an immutable claim to uniquely identify the user - a generated number or guid - in Facebook this is called user_id I believe

Another option for identifying the user is to send the token to the user info endpoint after validating it, to get the email, then match up to your application data on email. This can be useful when users already exist and you are changing the way they log in.

Some providers may issue a different user id per application, though this is not common - worth testing though.

In terms of supporting multiple issuers you have 2 main options:

- Get the issuer from the token at runtime and validate differently per issuer - again it is possible that some vendors don't set the iss claim according to standards
- Use federated sign in - as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548509/what-should-be-authentication-strategy-between-client-and-server-when-only-socia/59560235#59560235) - so that your applications only ever talk to one provider and code is simpler

Comment: Thanks for the response, Gary. I just want to confirm a few things ... 

The biggest thing that sticks out to me is **not all providers are standards based**? So there isn't really a "one size fits all" solution. If I am implementing multiple IDPs, I will need to look at each providers implementation? I cannot assume the implementation is the same for all providers? 

Maybe I'm having a case of the Mondays, but why bother creating a standard if top tech companies won't even follow it?

Comment: Indeed! Unfortunately all of the big vendors do things a little differently and maybe only support 80 percent of what you want. It is easy to be misled by their marketing - but I like your approach of starting with standards. I have a blog on this stuff - maybe see this post on the type of workaround that is sometimes needed: https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/